# Insert custom taxonomy into category query

Tags: custom-post-types, plugins, plugin-development, custom-taxonomy, filters

I created a custom taxonomy for a custom post but I have a problem. I would like to know how to enter the categories of custom taxonomy in the functions of my themes. It has some filter or something that can make so that whenever you have a query the "category" it also pick up the categories of "my_custom_taxonomy"

Comment: Could you explain your problem a little bit more?

Comment: I need something like 'pre_get_posts' but for categories replace default wordpress categories with  my_custom_taxonomy.

I made a plugin that creates a category taxonomy by wordpress and wanted to replace with a filter all querys from "category" to "my_custom_taxonomy". I can not be clearer than that.

Comment: thats unfortunate, i too don't quite understand.

Comment: @Craig Wayne I want here [link](https://imgur.com/a/PapUO25) to list the categories of my custom_taxonomy. I do not want to list categories of the category taxonomy of wordpress without having to make changes to the theme code.